# Is there a way to install softwares (offline) using some one else's apt-archives?

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software or packages without internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Is it possible to install softwares from backups of some else's /var/cache/apt/archives ?
It will be a grt discovery fr me if it could be possible. I have tried installing Gstreamer downloaded on Ubuntu 12 on Ubuntu 11 but it could not work.

What i did is I copied the archive dir which have the .deb files to my friends computer and tried to replace his archive dir with that. When I hit the install button (on Ubuntu Software Center) it started to downloading directly from net.

Can Gdebi package installer do that ? is there any other alternative to do this ?

Comment: There is a better way, use [aptoncd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/aptoncd). It just does what you want; makes a software repository on CD from archived packages.

Comment: How to use this aptoncd ?

Comment: It's available in software centre. But you can also download it from the link provided. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/APTonCD) is a step-by-step user-guide.

Comment: It should work, but you must use packages for the release you run. Trying to install packages for another release is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use a software called QApt.
QApt is a great software for installing local deb files that ubuntu uses for its packages.
To install QApt click [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/qapt-deb-installer/)
Also take a look here http://jontheechidna.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/introducing-qapt-and-the-muon-package-manager/